# Service validation: throw an exception if validation failed

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, validation, exception

I need your help!

In my web project (it based on Spring MVC) i'm using exceptions to indicate that some validation is failed, but i'm not sure that doing the right way.

For example i have such service:

```
@Service
@Transactional
public class UserService {

@Autowired
private UserRepository userRepository;

public User createUser(UserDTO userDTO) throws IllegalArgumentExceptio {
    validateUserEmail(userDTO);
    return userRepository.save(new User(userDTO.getFirstName(), userDTO.getLastName(), userDTO.getEmail(), userDTO.getPassword()));
}

private void validateUserEmail(UserDTO userDTO) throws IllegalArgumentException {
        String emailPattern = "^[a-z0-9-\\+]+(\\.[a-z0-9-]+)*@"
                + "[a-z0-9-]+(\\.[a-z0-9]+)*(\\.[a-z]{2,})$";

        if (userDTO() == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(INVALID_EMAIL_NULL.getMessage());
        } else if (userDTO().length() > 25) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(INVALID_EMAIL_LENGTH.getMessage());
        } else if (!userDTO().matches(emailPattern)) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(INVALID_EMAIL_FORMAT.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

I've read this one [article](http://martinfowler.com/articles/replaceThrowWithNotification.html). Also i know that there is another one approach is to use Hibernate Validator.

So, the main question is: which one approach is the best practice and why?

1. Throw an exception during validation as i do.
2. Use something like [notification pattern](http://martinfowler.com/articles/replaceThrowWithNotification.html).
3. Use Hibernate Validator.

Comment: Did my answer helped  ?

Comment: @javaguy Yes, it helped me. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clearly, using the **Hibernate Validator for Bean Validations, which is the readily available library** is the best approach as we don't need to rewrite huge code for min length/max length, etc.. validations explicitly.

Also, if you rewrite the logic for minlength/maxlength validations ourself, you need to do the extensive testing to ensure that the written code is correct, which is must.

The thumb rule, if some trusted code is already available, do not try to reinvent/rewrite again, rather just make use of it, which is called **DRY (Don't Repeat Yourself) principle**,  very important in any programming

Answer (score 0):

That's a very bad idea. One of issues with your solution that comes to my mind is like: How you are going to notify a user if your email validation fails? I would go for [custom validation annotation](https://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/07/spring-mvc-custom-validation-annotations.html). If validation of email fails, you simply return `false`. With that approach, you can also easy notify user if email validation fails because simply, `BindingResult` will contain errors. Also, another benefit is localization of error message. So yeah, Hibernate validatior is way to go.